# Getting Error when starting my Django server

Tags: python, django

I wrote new models, made migrations, migrated the models but forgot to register the models in the admin.py file. After migrating I started my server and got the following error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\ecommerce\ecommerce\urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    path('',include(('foodapp.urls', 'foodapp'), namespace='foodapp')),
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 1172, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

After getting this error I deleted my latest migration.py file but still getting the above exceptions while running my server.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the file `C:\Users\Bilawal Hassan\PycharmProjects\Ecommerce Website\ecommerce\ecommerce\urls.py` in line 27:

```py
path('',include(('foodapp.urls', 'foodapp'), namespace='foodapp')),
```

Looks like Django can't find the `foodapp` app, check if the app is installed, you haven't any typo, etc

Comment: application is installed, and is included in the settings.py file, pasting my installed_apps array. Also, there is no typo



`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'foodapp',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'crispy_forms'

]`

Comment: the issue can be related to the `foodapp/urls.py` file. If you comment out that line you will see that you (probably) can start your server normally

Comment: Yes, the issue was in this file because of bad characters, I pressed backspace 4 to 5 times and the error got fixed.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

delete your database,then use command python manage.py showmigrations
if migrations are not made then use the migrate commands,otherwise delete both migration file and database file.then create migrations.py and include **init**.py in it.then run migration commands.it will fix.

Comment: Hi, 

deleted my database, ran python manage.py showmigrations file but still getting the same error. 

Also, deleted the migrations file and still getting the same error upon running the server,